# What are some early signs of loose skin when trying to lose weight?

Tags: weight-loss, skin

I have recently started my weight loss journey to get rid of some excess fat I have. My goal is to lose about 50 lbs, in a year. I'm not really married to the whole timeline, so I would actually like to go slow, and might take it longer than a year too.

I recently (a month now) started my workout and and diet regime and it's going well so far, no more than a pound per week. That's good, but my question is, what are some early signs of loose skins, if any? I would really like to get out of this pot and without landing on fire.

I have been reading up on tips that help avoid loose skin: drink a lot of water, eat healthy, workout and tighten muscles rather, etc. But still, if there are any early signs of loose skin, I would like to know early on and, maybe slow down my progress, or even alter the regime, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50lbs a year equates to 1lb a week which is a healthy amount of weight to lose (http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/weight-loss-guide/Pages/losing-weight-getting-started.aspx). This should help you avoid getting loose skin. Losing too much weight to fast, as you correctly asserted, is usually the reason for loose skin. Take photos every month of yourself and review them, you should be able to see and feel the effects. Alternatively, ask to get a independent review from a doctor.